# finding equivalence classes of $D^n/S^{n-1}$ and this hoemomorphism with $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, geometric-topology

Collapsing the unit sphere of the unit ball $S^{n-1} \subset D^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to a point. How can I show that it ($D^n/S^{n-1}$) is homeomorphic to the sphere of one dimension higher ($S^n$)?

I thought about $D_n$ = {($x_1$, ..., $x_n$): $x_1$+$x_n$$\leqslant 1$} and $S_{n-1} = ${($x_1$, ..., $x_n$): $x_1$+...+$x_n$ = $1$}. So $D_n / S_{n-1}$ = $\bigcup_{z \in \left[-1, 1\right]}$ {($x_1$, ..., $x_n$, z): ${x_1}^2 + ... +
{x_n}^2 = 1 - z^2$} = $\bigcup_{z \in \left[-1, 1\right]}$ {($x_1$, ..., $x_n$, z): ${x_1}^2 + ... +
{x_n}^2 + z^2 = 1$}. And it is clearly similar to $S_{n}$. Can we use my idea to construct this homeomorphism sending ($x_1$, ..., $x_n$) in ($x_1$, ..., $x_n$, $z$)?

Comment: Please don't delete and reask the same question.

Comment: Note it is note the same original question.

Comment: Then you should edit the question to make explicit the distinction.

Comment: Sure, I'll do it at the next time.